# Disable future indexing in Elasticsearch CouchDB river

Tags: indexing, couchdb, elasticsearch

I have hundreds of small DBs in CouchDB which are not updated but I need to query them often. How do I disable future indexing so that Elasticsearch does not keep checking for changes and save my system resources? Presently I've setup the river with default bulk size and timeout of 100 and 10ms respectively for each DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the river using a command like below to remove the river by _type from Elasticsearch will ensure no future updates:

curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/_river/'_type'/'

Hope that helps.